# Python subprocess different ouput of same call on diffrent machines

Tags: python, python-3.x, window

I am trying to execute a java file with python using subprocess.
I have 2 machines, both have the same windows version and same python version. Even the path for the jar file is same on both the PCs.

I am trying to do the following

```
import subprocess
path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microchip\\MPLABX\\v5.35\\mplab_platform\\mplab_ipe\\ipecmd.jar"
subprocess.call(["java", "--jar", path])
```

This works on one PC but throws a FileNotFoundError on the other.

My first doubt was that it was because of spaces in the file path. But now after it worked on one, I am clueless.

Images attached for reference
[image: working instance]

[image: Not working instance]

### Update

So, problem was that the other machine did not have java. After installing it, I tried to tun the jar file from the command line which works. But on running it from the python script, it throws WinfError 193 (Image attached).

[image]
On referring it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-), it says, 193 stands for

> ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT
>
> 193 (0xC1)
>
> %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Now again the question is, if this can be executed from cmd, why is it causing problems when done with Python ?

Comment: Does it work when you run it on the command line (not inside python)? Maybe java isn't installed on one of the computers.

Comment: Oh yes! Java can be a problem... So stupid of me... I'll try and revert

Comment: Ok, so Java was the problem, I installed java and it runs from the cmd. But not it throws the error 193 when I try to run it from python